# Meta Tag Theme Color Isn't Actually Black When Set To #000000

Tags: html, meta-tags

So here's the code:

```html
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
```

The color isn't quite black: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR2n3.jpg

How can I make it look as black as the black border color on the link that I blurred?

Answer (score 1):

Because theme-color [does not work in any browser except Safari and Chrome Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta/name/theme-color#browser_compatibility) at this time.